# jquery Why the alert message is not being displayed?

Tags: jquery

Why the alert message is not being displayed ??

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>jQuery demo</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

       alert("Hi welcome to Jquery ");
     }
     );
   </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine.  I copied it into jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/c86w8/ and that works fine as well.  Are you sure you didn't accidentally disable alerts from your site?

Comment: What browser are you testing in? It is working for me in firefox, I am on ubuntu right now so I can't test IE.

Comment: I have tested in FF, IE and chrome and all working fine for me. Please provide more details about the browser you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my browser it works. Try making the following improvements to make it more compliant:

1) Add the attribute `type="text/javascript"` to your `script` tags.

2) Move the scripts to the `head` part of the document.

PS: You can use the following shorthand notation to have a function called when the document finishes loading:

```
$(function(){
    alert("Hi welcome to Jquery ");
});
```

Comment: actually `text/javascript` is deprecated. the recommended *mime* type is `type="application/javascript"`

Answer (score 2):

Change your script section to this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){

           alert("Hi welcome to Jquery ");
         }
         );
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

check if the jquery is loaded or not by

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    console.log("jQuery is not loaded");  
    //or
    alert("jQuery is loaded");  
} else {
    console.log("jQuery is not loaded");
     alert("jQuery is not loaded"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run this it does display the alert message, but what you may be experiencing is a race condition with loading the jQuery framework and using it in the `body` of the page. Try moving the `script` tag that loads jQuery into the `head` area of the page. This will make sure jQuery has loaded before the DOM tries to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Hi welcome to Jquery ");
});
```

is working fine.

My problem was the Firefox "screen-size-test" option. I tested for mobile version but the JS-Alert box was not displayed in the middle of the "screen-size test" but in the middle of screen itself, which became invisible due to the overlay of this option